# Is the follwoing function an example of an uniformly continuous function?

Tags: continuity, solution-verification, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

> Is $id$ an uniformly continuous function?

Let $(\mathbb{N},d)$ be a metric space such that $d(x,y) = |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$.

Let us consider the identity map $id:(\mathbb{N},d) \to (\mathbb{N},d_{disc})$ such that $id(x)=x$. Then we see that this map is continuous.

We know that the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is a cauchy sequence under the usual metric. We choose $\epsilon =1$ then we see that there exists $\mathbb{N_1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N_1}-1 < \frac{1}{n} <\frac{1}{N_1}+1$ for all $n \ge N_1$.

Let us consider the set $B_d(N_1,1) = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \ge N_1\}$ . Then this set is closed as $(N,d)$ has a discrete topology. Then $B_d(N_1,1)$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Then let us consider the function $id_{B_d(N_1,1)}$.If the function is uniformly continuous then we know that it maps cauchy sequences to cauchy sequences. Now consider the seqeunce $(n)$ where $n \ge N_1+1$ then $(n) \subset B_d(N_1,1)$ and it is also a cauchy sequence.

However, the sequence is not cauchy in $(N,d_{disc})$ as the only cauchy sequences in $(N,d_{disc})$ are the ones that are constant. Hence we know that $id_{B_d(\mathbb{N_1},1)}$ is not uniformly continuous.

> Is my proof okay?
>
> If this is okay can we consider $id$ as an example of a function which is continuous on a closed and bounded interval but not uniformly continuous. As the intervals of $\mathbb{N}$ under $d$ or under the usual induced metric is of the above form.

Comment: What is the question? That is, which is the function that you are trying to determine whether it is uniformly continuous or not? It seems to me that you write several times $N$ instead of $\Bbb N$. And when you claim that the sequece $\frac1n$ is a Cauchy sequence, that's with respect to which distance?

Comment: 1/n is caucjy under the usual metric. My question asks whether the function $id$ is uniformly continuous or not

Comment: And that function goes from which metric space into which metric space?